# Angularjs how to escape special characters

Tags: angularjs

In the following code how to escape special characters to display the html?

```
$scope.template_html='\u003cdiv class\u003d\"modal-body add_ticket\" id\u003d\"mymodal\"\u003e\r\n'
```

template

```
<div ng-bind-html="template_html"></div>
```

Comment: Which characters do you want to escape? Newline already is escaped (god knows why you want a newline in an HTML string) and for reasons only you know the angle brackets are replaced by codes and `"` is escaped although there's absolutely no reason for that. There are no special characters in this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) in your controller.

```
> decodeURIComponent('\u003cdiv class\u003d\"modal-body \" id\u003d\"mymodal\"\u003e\r\n')"
<div class="modal-body" id="mymodal">
```